# How to declare Singleton instance in Kotlin , is it similar to how we declare Singleton class?

Tags: kotlin, singleton

In an interview I was told to write a Singleton class so I wrote the following code

```
  object Ant{

    }
```

but later he asked me to write Singleton instance which confused me and I ended up writing like this

```
  object what{

   }
```

now, I know I am wrong but I am really curious how to write down Singleton Instance.

Comment: interesting. maybe the interviewer doesn't understand Kotlin object.

Comment: I use companion object to expose a volatile object for my class and use that object

Comment: AMIN PAN so, what I did was correct?

Answer (score 1):

please check my helper class, What I was using might be wrong so please correct me

```
class Helper{

    companion object{

    @Volatile
    var INSTANCE : Helper? = null

    fun getInstance(): Helper {
        return INSTANCE?: synchronized(this){
            val instance = Helper()
            INSTANCE = instance
            instance
        }
    }

  }

}
```

and then I would create a variable like this `val helper = Helper.getInstance()` and use this object from then on, sometimes I declare them as global variables outside class to make it easier to access across the app

recently we have shifted to Koin so we just declare these classes as singleton by using `@Single` ksp annotation

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to guess what an interviewer was asking about, after the event, but in your code above there is no *instance* of either `Ant` or `What` yet, only the object declaration.  You would need to instantiate the object like:

```
val mySingleton = What
```

Object declarations are [initialized lazily when first used](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#semantic-difference-between-object-expressions-and-declarations)

Comment: Good spot in the docs — but I don't think that makes any _practical_ difference. The implementation is free to create an instance as soon as the `object` class is loaded, or as late as it's first used — because there's no practical way the program could find out. And unless the interviewer gave any hints about class loading or similar, I wouldn't expect him to have that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were right!

In Kotlin, an `object` *is* a singleton: it defines a class, with exactly one instance. (That one instance is created automatically, and you can't create any others.) So if you need a singleton, that's the standard way to get it.

You *could* do something like:

```
class Ant private constructor() {
    companion object {
        val INSTANCE = Ant()
    }
}
```

That's how you'd have to do it in Java: a private constructor and a single static instance. It may be that your interviewer was more familiar with Java, and was expecting you to do that — but that's absolutely pointless in Kotlin, because `object` does exactly the same, only more concisely (and with less opportunity for errors or race conditions or whatever).

If you were using a framework such as Spring, that provides other ways of creating single instances (e.g. with annotations such as `@Component`, `@Bean`, etc.) but those are specific to the framework, so you'd probably know if you needed anything like that.

Or your interviewer may have something else in mind — but in that case, he should have given you some hints; you're not a mind-reader!

The bottom line is that without any further information, `object` is the most obvious way to get a singleton, so from what you've posted, you were right.

Comment: The interviewer was more familiar to java yes and he was taking interview of Android and that's why he even asked me to write and he even gave the reason for rejection as one of these (can't write Singleton)

Comment: If the singleton needs a Context parameter, then you need to do it the Java way, and should probably use doubly-locked synchronized access.